# how to send string array from custom adpter to main activity

Tags: android, android-contacts, sendmessage, custom-adapter

I am a new android Developer and i want to send String Array from Custom ADapter to main activity class but my code is not working and I am Using CustomAdapter class please can any help me

My ContactList class is following.....

```
public class ContactList extends Activity {
    ListView lvContacts;
    List<String> listname;
    List<String> listnumber;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> arr;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> arrnumber;
    Button smsbtn;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        smsbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sms);
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, };
        Cursor c1 = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                null, null, null);
            listname = new ArrayList<String>();
        listnumber = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (c1.moveToNext()) {
            String name = c1
                    .getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String number = c1
                    .getString(c1
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            listname.add(name);
            listnumber.add(number);
        }
        c1.close();
        Object[] obj = listname.toArray();
        Object[] objnumber = listnumber.toArray();
        arr = new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
        String[] da = new String[obj.length];
        String[] danumber = new String[objnumber.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            danumber[i] = (String) objnumber[i];
            da[i] = (String) obj[i];
            arr.add(new PhoneList(da[i], danumber[i], i));
        }
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
        CustomAdapter adpttt = new CustomAdapter(ContactList.this,
                R.layout.contacts_list_item, arr);
        listView.setAdapter(adpttt);
        smsbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                String[] myStrings = intent.getStringArrayExtra("numberarray");
                for (int i = 0; i < myStrings.length; i++) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), myStrings[i],
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

}
```

My Custom Adapter Class is Following....

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PhoneList> {
    int inflatr;
    Context ctxt;
    boolean bulkflag = false;
    static int k=0;
    ArrayList<PhoneList> data=new ArrayList<PhoneList>();
    private static final String[] arr1=new String[256];
    private static String[] arr=new String[256];
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<PhoneList> arr) {

        super(context, resource, arr);
        this.inflatr = resource;
        this.ctxt = context;
        this.data= arr;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         UserHolder holder = null;
         View row = convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
             LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) ctxt).getLayoutInflater();
             row = inflater.inflate(inflatr, parent, false);
             holder = new UserHolder();
             holder.textName=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.lblName);
             holder.stnumber=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.mobilenum);
             holder.checked=(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check);

//           holder.btnEdit = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.atomPay_removePay);
             row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
             holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();            
        }
         final PhoneList dta=data.get(position);
         holder.checked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                 int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                 data.get(position).setselect(!data.get(position).getSelect());
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
                 arr=dta.getnumberr();
                 arr1[k]=arr[position];
            }
        });

         holder.checked.setChecked(dta.getSelect());

         holder.checked.setTag(position);
        for(int i=0; i<=data.size(); i++)
        {
            holder.textName.setText(dta.getName());
        }
        for(int j=0; j<=data.size(); j++)
        {
            holder.stnumber.setText(dta.getNumber());
        }

//      holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
//          
//          @Override
//          public void onClick(View v) {
//              Toast.makeText(ctxt, "Humayoon    Siddiqueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"+dta.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//              Intent moreIntent=new Intent(getContext(),ContactList.class);
//              String tName=dta.getName();
//              moreIntent.putExtra("Template",tName);
//              v.getContext().startActivity(moreIntent);
//               // ctxt.startActivity(ctxt,ContactList.class);
//          }
//      });
        Intent ii=new Intent(getContext(),ContactList.class);
        ii.putExtra("numberarray", arr1);
        return row;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textAddress;
        TextView textLocation;
        ImageButton btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
        TextView stnumber;
        CheckBox checked;
        }


}
```

My xml Layout is following....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@layout/bg_player_header"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvContacts"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="422dp"
        android:divider="#FFEEEE" >
</ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sms"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="109dip"
        android:text="Send Sms"
        android:onClick="btnclicked"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why are to declaring arr1 as **final** , remove that.

Comment: private static String[] arr1=new String[256];

Comment: because i strore specific numbers in array and multiple time getnumrr funtion call of phonlist class the array loss value

Comment: And why are showing so many strings in a toast consecutively? that's very bad

Comment: broo thats are for just testing only not a app part

Comment: private static String[] arr1=new String[256]; in which 256 means total number which store in a sim card

Comment: can you tell me the solution plzz

Comment: change **private static final String[] arr1=new String[256];** to **private static String[] arr1=new String[256];** ; change **if(convertView==null)** to **if(row==null)**, and add what Boban has told you, apply the code that John have give. Method inside the **CustomAdapter** class.

Comment: And for debugging use **Log**, like **Log.i("check", myStrings[i]);** this will be shown in the Logcat.

Comment: after writing the mehtod that John said, use this in your main activity: **String[] myStrings = adpttt.getData();**

Comment: "My code is not working" is not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function in your custom adapter for getting data you need. You need to have reference of the adapter in your main activity class.

Comment: I cant understand plz see my full code i want to send an string array from custom adapter too main activity

Comment: you cant send it, you need to have function in you adapter like `getData()` and you need to call that function from your activity.

Comment: this is what he means: `public String[] getData() { return arr1 }`. This will be in your adapter class. Then you call `getData()` from your activity class. This way the array is returned to your activity when you call `adapter.getData()`

Comment: because when i create a reference of customedapter in main activity that force me to declare null because custom adapter constructor is argumented and due too this null pointer exception and code is not working

Comment: the reason why the OP is confused is because your explanation is non-existent